# How did Chomsky's Universal Grammar impact language learning theory in the 1950s and 1960s?

Tags: theory

Many people nowadays know [Noam Chomsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noam_Chomsky) mainly as a social critic and political activist. For those who have a background in linguistics, he is a major figure in twentieth-century linguistics. One of the concepts introduced by Chomsky is [universal grammar (UG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_grammar). How did this concept impact language learning theory in the 1950s and 1960s?

Comment: Most people in the computer science field (especially those who work in the programming languages area) are familiar with him for the [Chomsky Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy), which defines concepts like context-free grammars, regular expressions (regex), etc. Although the concepts were linguistic in origin, they are the cornerstones of parser design. And there is scarcely a programmer around who hasn't used a regex for one thing or another.

Comment: @MikeHarris Your comment would be the starting point of a good answer on a computer-science-related site, but I'm sure you know that LLSE is not that kind of site. Programming languages are off-topic here.

Comment: Absolutely! (That's why it's a comment, and not an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that it largely resulted in the development of the [Audio-Lingual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio-lingual_method) and [Direct Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_method_(education)) teaching methodologies.

Have a look at this list of language teaching [methodologies](http://esl.fis.edu/teachers/support/method.htm).  It gives a good overview of language teaching methodologies.

Comment: Could you support the first line of your answer with arguments or citations to reliable literature?